# Singleton class working on 4.0 iOS and earlier version but not on 4.1 and 4.2 SDK

Tags: iphone, ios4, singleton, ios-4.2

I am using Singleton Class to share huge data I am getting from webservice to handle, which I have done in my previous apps also. But with new ios 4.2 its not working, I can't understand the reason of it not working as it has nothing to do with new api/frameworks.

Here is the code of my singleton:

```
 @interface SingleTon : NSObject {

  NSMutableArray *hname;

}
+ (SingleTon *) sharedInstanceHname;

//hname
-(NSMutableArray *) getHname:(NSMutableArray  *)x;
-(void) setHname:(NSMutableArray  *)x;
```

.m class:

@implementation SingleTon
     static SingleTon  *_sharedInstanceHname;

```
 - (id) init
 {
if (self = [super init])
{
    // custom initialization
    //memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
    hname = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"NO RESULT",nil];

    index =1;
}
return self;
```

}

```
  + (SingleTon *) sharedInstanceHname
  {
if (!_sharedInstanceHname)
{
    _sharedInstanceHname = [[SingleTon alloc] init];
}

return _sharedInstanceHname;
```

}

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getHname:(NSMutableArray *)x
 { 
return hname;
  }

- (void) setHname:(NSMutableArray *)x
{
hname = x;
 }
```

Here how i am using Singleton to store value in my first view:

```
    SingleTon *sname = [SingleTon sharedInstanceHname];
 [sname setHname:hname];
```

And here is how i am accessing this set value in second view viewDidLoad method:

```
    SingleTon *places = [SingleTon sharedInstanceHname];
NSLog(@"%@", [places getHname:getname]);
```

I tried all possible retain release but of no use...and yea error also varies..some time it is “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”  and some time other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `initWithObjects:`, you should terminate list of values with `nil`. Except this is a typo you made while preparing the example.

Also, there could be a problem with your `setHname:` method neither retaining nor copying the value being assigned.

Comment: Could you update your example code to what it looks like now? For further investigation, you could (you should, actually) look into stack trace at the moment your app crashes and examining values of variables you have to understand what's going on. Also, try turning on NSZombieEnabled environment variable to, probably, get a bit more valuable error info (read about it e.g. [here](http://www.tomwhitson.co.uk/blog/2009/04/debugging-with-nszombiesenabled/)).

Comment: You need to thoroughly read and understand [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Right now, your shared instance doesn't own the array after `setHname:` has been called, but instead references to it, in a weak manner. It also doesn't release previous value which leads to memory leak.